# How to repair crack in children's slide

Tags: repair, crack, plastic

I've got a nasty crack in my kids' slide ( *see image* ).

I think the slide is plastic and I'm sure the crack will only grow if used.

Is there a way to repair this?

[image: crack in slide]

Comment: I'd do a backer plate and some kind of bolt going through the part where a kid might be that has a flush or rounded head. Probably 4 screws on each side of the crack. Also drill out the end of the crack so it stops spreading.

Comment: Do you want to take that chance of "repairing" something that your kids and neighbor's kids will be using? It cracked for a reason and will likely crack again no matter what you do. Buy a new one. Stay safe where ever you are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace it. The integrity is now compromised. Do not risk child safety over cheap plastic.

No adhesive, epoxy, resin or anything like that will return the original strength of the slide and any ideas involving screwing backing plates in sound good, but once you start drilling holes or screwing through things you are going to weaken the slide in multiple areas to try to save another and risk making it worse.

It may be disappointing for your child and they may have to wait before you can replace it but that's better than a trip to A and E.

Can I get an Amen?

Sorry about your slide, it looks like a good one too.

Comment: Fair advice but not quite an answer to the question . I've been very lucky and managed to get the company I bought it from to replace it

Comment: Oh well I'm glad that's sorted then, I just worry when it comes to kids, baby sister is only 3 so if I wouldn't do it for her I wouldn't advise it. I'm the fixit man of the family so whenever something breaks she comes to me aha!!